# Replacing emoji with text in python pandas?

Tags: python, dictionary

How to replace the Values of the dictionary with the keys of the dictionary in the Data?

I have this dictionary

```
Dict = {' butterfly': "Ƹ̵̡Ӝ̵̨̄Ʒ'",
 ' clapping hands': "o/', '*o/*'",
 ' face with raised eyebrow': "O?O'",
 ' face with symbols on mouth': ">.'",
 ' grimacing face': "e.e', 'O.e', 'O.e'",
 ' rolling on the floor laughing': "m/*.*m/'"}

Keys = text/meaning of emoji, 
Values = emoji,
```

I want to replace the emoji(`values`) with the text(`key`) in my data.

Please suggest any better way to proceed.

sample data which has emoji....

.@AnnaKendrick47 My set up at the electronics boat at work. ^_^ 
 "Fun update for everyone who's requested, #EW is now IN!! @WordsWFriends\n ⬇️ ⬇️ ⬇️ 
 '@AnnaKendrick47 please sing @DrewGasparini \'s Circus""',

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide a sample of the input data? Why is the dictionary defined this way, and not with the emoji as the keys, which seems more logical given your use case?

Comment: How does your data look like? Are they sentences or words?

Comment: Ohkay ,I can change the dictionary as emoji in the keys and Text in the Values .....and we have a sample data which has emojis in it ,which needed to be replaced with the text....is there any other approach you think?

Comment: the data is tweets /twitter data /sentence but also has emoji in it.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be like this:

```
>>> [k for k,v in Dict.iteritems() if v==">.'"]
[' face with symbols on mouth']
```

But if you can define the dictionary however you like, it would probably be better to do so with the emoji as the keys rather than the values. If you can't change the definition, you could define a second dictionary this way round:

```
>>> dict2 = dict(zip(Dict.values(),Dict.keys()))
>>> dict2[">.'"]
' face with symbols on mouth'
```

Comment: i have a  column which consist of lot of data in it and dealing individually will be tough...can we do it in other way

Comment: If you can provide a better example of what you are trying to do, it will be more straightforward for people to assist. For example, if you can provide a sample of the data.

Comment: Yes , I have already provided the dictionary and i want to make changes to my Data .

Comment: Yes, like I said if you can provide a sample of your *data* it would be helpful for assisting you

Comment: i have providede the data above , i hope that will help you